# How to update CDN from rails app

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

When i run the command rake assets:precomplie for production evn. then assets is updating on locally but did not update on cloudfront cdn files like (http://***/assets/pages/***!-cc5be2564b7a1c153e5f74c677795613.js). old assets is serving but  not new updated assets serving. can  you please provide any help to me that how can we update cdn assets.

Comment: Did you set `config.action_controller.asset_host` in your production.rb file?

Comment: yes, i did and compile

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the `config.action_controller.asset_host` directive to your CDN url?

Make sure the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable is properly set to production. You can also prepend it to the full command: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`.

Answer (score 0):

Within `config/environments/production.rb` you will see a setting `asset_host` that is responsible for prepending a domain onto all asset links created via the built in asset helpers

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.action_controller.asset_host = "<YOUR DISTRIBUTION SUBDOMAIN>.cloudfront.net"
```

Once deployed, this application will now serve all assets through the CloudFront distribution.

For more details : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn

One more thing:

If you want to precompile your assets in production mode then check in **production.rb**:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.compile = true  # make it false if you don't want to let heroku precompile everytime
```

And then Run this below in your terminal:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

then deploy I hope this helps you :)

Comment: No, It is not working on my case, i did those way but CDN did not update.